# using SpringMVC trying to upload a multipart file to get response in a perticular div,but the multipart file returns null in controller

Tags: html, spring-mvc

1. I have configured a multipart resolver in my dispatcher servlet.
   st item
2. I want the result to be reflected in a particular div.
3. My motive for geting the response in particular div is fulfilled using ajax but my image file is not reached to the controller hence gives error that **image upload returns null**.
4. The image file is not able to reach the controller and returns null.
5. I want that my image file should b recieved by the controller.
   and also the response should be on a div called **"harryPAGE"**

my jsp form page is

```
 <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="uploadBean"
    action="url"//this action takes to controller with request mapping as "hello"
     commandName="uploadBean">
    <table class="standardTable">

        <tr>
            <td>File</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="fileData" id="fileData" size="50"
                 required="required"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2 align="left"><input
                class="btn right breadPrevious" type="submit" value="Upload"
                 /></td>


        </tr>

    </table> 

<script>

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
    });

    $("form").submit(

            function() {
                alert("hi");
                var value = $("#fileData");
                alert(value);

                $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(),
                        function(html) {
                            $("#harryPAGE").html(html);
                        });
                return false; // prevent normal submit
            });



    </script>
    <c:out value="${message}"></c:out>
</form:form>
```

my controller class is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public  ModelAndView uploadImage(@ModelAttribute ImageUploadBean uploadBean,HttpServletRequest req) {
    int test=5; 

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("apage");
    try {
        System.out.println(req.getParameter("fileData"));
        MultipartFile imgFile = uploadBean.getFileData();

        test=imageService.uploadImage(imgFile);
        if(test==1){

            modelAndView.addObject("message","some message");           }
        else if(test==0){

            modelAndView.addObject("message","some message");           }               
    } catch (Exception e) {//the control enters here and gives exception
        logger.error("Unable to upload image " + e.getMessage(), e);
        modelAndView.addObject("message","some error");     }
    return modelAndView;
}
```

my dispatcher servlet .xml file is i have configured multipart resolver

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">     
<!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->   
<property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000"/>  
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to the form :)